# If statement in Robot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I've got this robot code:

```
Load staging server if available
    Open Browser    http://abc  Firefox
    ${text}=  Get Text  //h4
    Run Keyword If  ${text} != Hooray  Go To  http://xyz
```

On this I get error:  `Evaluating expression 'Hooray != Hooray' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`

What I'm trying to do is if the header tag in `abc` doesn't contain the word `hooray` redirect to `xyz`.

According to this topic [how to use "Run Keyword If" in robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763244/how-to-use-run-keyword-if-in-robot-framework#26768943) it should work but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer: [Use of "If statement" in robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023019/use-of-if-statement-in-robot-framework)

Try changing:

```
Run Keyword If  ${text} != Hooray  Go To  http://xyz
```

to:

```
Run Keyword If  "${text}" != "Hooray"  Go To  http://xyz
```

Comment: Yep ... that was it. I needed to add quotes to those values. Will accept as an answer asap.